# How to get a string between two substrings?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have the following text from a text file.

`#AAA#WantedData#bbb#ccc#ddd#eee#SoOn#`

I want to get only the `WantedData` from the above string. Always I want to get the data between second and third `#`sign.

What is the efficient way to achieve this in `python`?

Answer (score 1):

> **Python String split() Method**
>
> The split() method splits a string into a list.
>
> You can specify the separator, default separator is any whitespace.

```
data.split("#") # ['', 'AAA', 'WantedData', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'SoOn', '']
```

you can do it just like this(if you always want data between second and third #sign.):

```
data = "#AAA#WantedData#bbb#ccc#ddd#eee#SoOn#"
print (data.split("#")[2])
```

output:

```
WantedData
```

Comment: Thanks you! It looks easier than expected.